# hidden field within user control has value on client but not on server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a .aspx page that contains multiple user controls.

One of the user controls, let's call it UC0, contains four dynamically placed instances of another user control, let's call it UC1.

The display property of the UC1's is set to "block' or "none" based on a user preference but will always display at least one UC1 control.

Within user control UC1 I have a hidden field. I set the value of the hidden field in javascript and can see the values set there.

When I try to retrieve the values on the server side the value is an empty string.

If I place just a single instance of UC1 within UC0 then I can see the server side value as expected.

The dynamic user controls have unique ID's but the hidden field's ID's are the same.

I tried adding the hidden fields dynamically and giving each a unique ID but I still get the same results.
Is there something I could be missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Is there something I could be missing?` Yes, you forgot to add the relevant code to your post.

Comment: Please read the [How to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section to get familiar with basic rules of how to post a good question. This question does not show any concrete effort. You need to provide some stuff you have tried and describe the place you got stuck in.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post, your page renders a hidden field that has no value.  Then you execute JavaScript which does reflect the proper changes, but the value isn't reflected on the server.

The reason is how Web Forms framework actually works.  It follows a life cycle, without special controls or Ajax the server holds the initial value.  So when you modify via JavaScript the server is still unaware of the change.  JavaScript inherently affects the client, not server.

[image]

If you use an `UpdatePanel` or Ajax for instance it would rectify.  It'll send the data back to the server.

```
axios({
     method: '',
     url: '',
     data: ''
}).then(function(response) {

});
```

That would be one approach.

Comment: Greg, thanks for your reply. I understand the page lifecycle. With the scenario described above, if I only place a single UC1 within UC0 then I can see the value that I set in javascript on the server during postback. It is only when I place multiple instances of UC1 within UC0 that the value is an empty string on the server.
I am trying to figure out what is different when one UC1 exist and when multiple UC1 instance exist. Also I tried using telerik RadAjaxPanel to wrap the hidden field  and well as then other controls within the UC1 but I got the same results.

Comment: @gmangrant Are you trying to place the same control multiple times on the page?  That won't work because each control requires a specific id.  Only one per page.

Comment: Yes Greg, that is exactly what I was trying to do. There can be up to four UC1s within UC0. I also tried dynamically placing the hidden field in each UC1 control and give them unique names but that did not work either. I'm continuing to peck away at this and hope to find a solution because it is functionality the user desires.

Comment: You won’t find it because it is not supported.  One id, per page.  If you use id = “abc” you cannot use “abc” as an id on another element or control.  You can use JSX templates, to pull layouts and modify values though.

Comment: I may not have been clear earlier. All of the UC controls have unique ID's. They are placed dynamically and their ID's are different for each placement. It is the Hidden Field within the UC1 that have the same ID but there is only one per UC1 instance.